# Object actor is not a member of package akka

Tags: java, scala, akka

I am absolutely brand new to Scala and even java.Forget about akka framework. I am trying to setup my windows(64) machine to run scala and an akka actor model example. However after running the following command.

```
H:\ALLDOS\akka-2.0.5>scalac -cp lib\akka\akka-actor-2.0.5.jar -classpath "*.jar:dependencies/*.jar" tutorial\pi.scala
```

I am getting this error

```
tutorial\pi.scala:6: error: object actor is not a member of package akka import akka.actor._
```

The line 6 of pi.scala is

```
import akka.actor._
```

Please tell me the basics of how to resolve this error.

Scala version is `2.9.3`
Java is `1.7.079`
Akka installed is `2.0.5`.
I am running through a command prompt and not through sbt.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you not try to issue the scala compiler command by hand. When you are learning a new, complex system, there are many things that have to be wired up just so. If you use the Typesafe Activator - https://www.typesafe.com/activator/download - or `sbt` command, or even using Eclipse with Scala.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to properly list the latest dependency in the `build.sbt` file.
For akka actor it's:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.4"
```